# Running GitList or git stash on Synology

Tags: git

I am wondering why no one has done an App for Synology DiskStation that can run any Git.

Like GitList or Stash?
If you are using Source Control on a Synology Server / DiskStation, do you have a link to any information?

Thanks

Comment: If you're thinking about doing this yourself check out the [Synology 3rd Party Apps Developer Guide](http://download.synology.com/download/ds/userguide/Synology_DiskStation_Manager_3rd_Party_Apps_Developer_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for info. if I only had the time. http://gitlabhq.com/

Comment: I am using GitList on Synology server. It is realy easy to setup.

Comment: @jmelosegui I constantly get an exception that I should specify the repositories directory, which is in the config of course. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @0x0me did you add the repositories path to the open_basedir PHP setting???

If not go to [Control Panel->Web Services->PHP Settings] and add the repositories path to the open_basedir setting

Comment: @jmelosegui thanks you very much. This was the missing setting - no it works fine.